# UISplitViewController push animation glitch with hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My app contains UISplitViewController with 2 UITabBarControllers in master view. My second UITabBarController has "Hides Bottom Bar When Pushed" option enabled.

[image]

It leads to a strange animation glitch as presented in gif below (see right top and bottom corners). How can I eliminate this?

[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is UIKit bug. The chain of UISplitViewController -> Navigation -> UITabBarController -> ... leads to such artifact on pushing controllers.
To mitigate this you can **disable translucency** for UITabBar.